# Issue with understanding example on Javascriptissexy.com

Tags: javascript, scope, callback

```
var name = "Richard";

function not(f) {
    return function() {
        console.log("This: " + this);
        var result = f.apply(this);
        return result;
    };
}
function test () {
    var name = "Rob";
    console.log("Result: " + this.name);
    return this.name; // Richard (not Rob, because "this" refers to the window object, and it uses the name variable from the global window object)
}
var news = not (test);
news ();
```

Above is the code I was trying to understand from following website :  http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Here the author mentions that output should be "Result: Richard", but the console output is "Result: result"

Kindly explain the reason for discrepancy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ratuqi/1/edit?js,console — I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Because `this` as the comment in the code mentions is going to be the global `window` object. So `this.name` is `window.name` which is the name of the window. You are more than likely entering the code into an editor like jsfiddle or similar site where the default action is to wrap the entered js code in an onload / dom ready event. Which would cause the first `var name` not to be global and causing `window.name` to not be set to `Richard`

Comment: @PatrickEvans : Yes, you are correct. I was trying to implement it in jsfiddle. But I am curious how does the value of variable name is set to "result" in jsfiddle?

Comment: @Quentin: Should I use JSBIN for posting any javascript queries in future? Your guidance is appreciated.

Comment: No. Questions should include everything needed in the question itself. Stackoverflow includes provision to run live demos in questions and answers. I'd only use third party sites to host code demos for *comments*.

Comment: Because it is the name of the iframe that jsfiddle uses for the result pane, ie `<iframe name="result">`

Comment: @PatrickEvans : Thanks for the answer :-)